# How can I turn a CSV file into a web-based SQL database table, without having any database already setup?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, csv

Currently, I have a CSV file with data in it. I want to turn it into a SQL table, so I can run SQL queries on it. I want the table to be within a web-based database that others in my organization can also access. What's the easiest way to go from CSV file to this end result? Would appreciate insight on setting the up database and table, giving others access, and getting data inside. Preferably PostgreSQL, but MySQL is fine too.

Comment: Google `LOAD DATA INFILE` for mysql.Also sql server is a different beast.

Comment: I'm very interested to know how a web-based SQL database table.

Answer (score 0):

To create the table it depends on the number of columns you have. If you have only a few then do it manually:

```
CREATE TABLE <table name> (<variable name> <variable type (e.g. int or varchar(100)>, <etc.>)
```

If you have many columns you can open the csv file in excel and get 'SQL Converter for Excel' which will build a create statement for you using your column headings (and autodetect variable types too).

Loading data from a csv is also pretty straightforward:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <filepath (e.g. 'C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/test.csv'>
INTO TABLE <table name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS; (Only use this line if you have column names included in the csv).
```

As for a web-based solution: https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-sql/

Answer (score 0):

That's a relatively open-ended question. A couple of noteworthy pointers off the top of my head:

- MySQL allows you to store your data in different formats, one of them being CSV. That's a very straightforward solution if you're happy with it and don't mind a few limitations (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html).
- Otherwise you can import your data into a table with a full-featured engine (see other answer(s) for details).
- If you're happy with PostgreSQL and look for fully web based solution, have a look at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com).
- There are a great many ways to make your data available through web services without accessing the back-end data store directly. Have a look at REST and SOAP for instance.

HTH